# Using TransformationFunction

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, geometric-transform

I try to use the result from the function `FindGeometricTransform`. It returns an error and a `TransformationFunction`.

The `TransformationFunction` is technically a $4\times 4$ matrix. But how can I use the result? It is not really a $4\times 4$ matrix like

```
(m = {{1., 0., 0., 1.}, {0., 1., 0., 2.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 
     0., 1.}}) // MatrixForm

result = FindGeometricTransform[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 4, 0}}, {{1, 2, 0}, {3, 
     2, 0}}];
```

I would like to multiply the `TransformationFunction` with `m`. How can I do that? Trying `result[[2]].m` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [`TransformationMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationMatrix.html?q=TransformationMatrix) instead of the `TransformationFunction`:

```
TransformationMatrix@result[[2]]
```

> `{{0., -1., 0., 4.}, {1., 0., 0., 1.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}`

```
TransformationMatrix@result[[2]].m
```

> `{{0., -1., 0., 2.}, {1., 0., 0., 2.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the matrix from `result` using `Part`:

```
result[[2, 1]].m
```

> ```
> {{0., -1., 0., 2.}, {1., 0., 0., 2.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Karsten shows what you can do if you want the homogeneous matrix and not the `TransformationFunction[]` itself. If you want a `TransformationFunction[]` result, use `Composition[]`:

```
result = FindGeometricTransform[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 4, 0}}, {{1, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0}}];
m = {{1., 0., 0., 1.}, {0., 1., 0., 2.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}};

Composition[result[[2]], TransformationFunction[m]]
   TransformationFunction[{{0., -1., 0., 2.}, {1., 0., 0., 2.},
                           {0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}]
```